# REST - mark entries read/unread

Tags: java, string, rest

I did this simple RESP app for entering blog entries to an html page, here is a sample code..  any ideas why? As I googles it looks it should be ok.. I am showing you what i did.. every entry has its id, its saved in an arraylist and has just a simple attribute text.. i wanna add some special commands later, so I can add an event in command line as well.. I wanna add a function that I can mark it as read/unread, by default unread.. any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

```
@Path("/")
public class RootResource {
private final EntryListResource entries = new EntryListResource();

@GET
@Path("favicon.ico")
public Response getFavicon() {
    return Response.noContent().build();
}

@GET
public Response get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    final URI location = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("/entries").build();
    return Response.seeOther(location).build();
}

@Path("entries")
public EntryListResource getEntries() {
    return entries;
}
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entryRef")
public class EntryResourceRef {
private int id;
private URI href;

@XmlAttribute
public URI getHref() {
    return href;
}

@XmlAttribute
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setHref(URI href) {
    this.href = href;
}
}
```

finally

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class EntryResource {
private int id;
private String text;


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response get() {
    return Response.ok(this).build();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response getHTML(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 @PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response updatePlain(String text,String description, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    return update(text, description, uriInfo.getAbsolutePath());
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response updateAsForm(@FormParam("text") String text, @FormParam("description") String description,@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    return update(description,text, uriInfo.getAbsolutePath());
}

private Response update(String text,String description, URI self) {
    if (getText().equals(text)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(
                                          Response
                                          .status(Response.Status.CONFLICT)
                                          .entity("The blog entry text has not been modified")
                                          .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                          .build()
                                          );
    }
    setText(text);
    return Response.seeOther(self).build();
}
```

sources

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class EntryListResource {

private final AtomicInteger nextEntryId = new AtomicInteger(0);
private UriInfo uriInfo = null;


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response get() {
    return Response.ok(this).cacheControl(CC).build();
}

@XmlElement(name = "blog")
public Collection<EntryResourceRef> getEntries() {
    final Collection<EntryResourceRef> refs = new ArrayList<EntryResourceRef>();
    for (final EntryResource entry : entries.values()) {
        final EntryResourceRef ref = new EntryResourceRef();
        ref.setId(entry.getId());
        ref.setHref(getEntryUri(entry));
        refs.add(ref);
    }
    return refs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use 0 and 1 which will help you to sort the results.

While fetching records you may append "Read" or "Unread" in the query itself. Example is given below

```
Select news.*, 
(case news.STATUS
when 0 then 'Unread' 
when 1 then 'Read' 
end) as Status
from News news
```

This was a native SQL or you can do in HQL as well.

Other solution can be you may take an enum in your News entity. This By this you can get string to be shown in UI and in DB it will save ordinal value i.e. 0 or 1. Example code is given below.

```
@Table(name = "NEW")
public class New 
{
    private NewsStatus newsStatus;
}


public static enum NewsStatus {
    READ{
        public String toString(){
            return "Read";
        }
    }, 
    UNREAD{
        public String toString(){
            return "Unread";
        }
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.ordinal() + 1;
    }
    public String getLabel(){
        return this.toString();
    }
    public static NewsStatus getByLabel(String label) 
    {
        if(label == null)
            return null;
        for(NewsStatus ns : NewsStatus.values()) {
            if(label.equalsIgnoreCase(ns.getLabel()))
                return ns;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static NewsStatus getByValue(int value){
        return NewsStatus.values()[value-1];
    }
}
```

Do let me know if further details are required?

Krish

Comment: Thank you. I just have problem insert it in the JSF. Which method here should I call with the buttoncommand?